# Why no support for Whipper - cd ripping software?

Tags: python, repository, python3, ruby, cd-ripping

Curious why Whipper isn't available from Ubuntu repos?

You may be curious why I'm after that when there is other software out there. Well, it and RubyRipper were developed after ExactAudioCopy (EAC), a Windows bit of software that is designed to give more exact rips. RubyRipper is built off ruby while Whipper is built with python. From what I can find, Whipper is further along and better 'supported' in terms of updates and fixes.

I did recently find RubyRipper on https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/xenial/apps/getdeb/rubyripper which apprently belongs to "getdeb aps"?

So, unless I'm missing something, I'm under the impression that Whipper is the way to go. Would appreciate suggestions or corrections.

Comment: Beware casting stones "Hey this isn't supported!" Better to ask: "Is this available?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is available in Ubuntu: https://snapcraft.io/whipper

That's right, it's a snap.

In fact, there's a link to it on the [Whipper github page](https://github.com/whipper-team/whipper#package).